# How to write and accept XML nodes..here 'node' doesnot exist and 'e' is not exist in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
public void readxml()
{
    lobtype = Convert.ToString(Session["ddlvalue"]);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"\Files\" + lobtype + ".xml"));
    TreeNode treenode = (TreeNode)e.Node;
    XmlNode xmlnode = (XmlNode)e.Node.DataItem;
    if (xmlnode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (xmlnode.Attributes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Attributes.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode childnode = new TreeNode(
                    "@" + xmlnode.Attributes[i].Name,
                    "@" + xmlnode.Attributes[i].Name);
                treenode.ChildNodes.Add(childnode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to assign node to `treenode` in controller? Here I am facing error:

> The name 'Node' does not exist in the current context and 'e' is does not exist

Comment: add your xml file to the question

Comment: Where is variable `e` defined?

Comment: iam not defined 'e'..iam wrote this code in MvcController..iam asking solve pbolem.aruguments are not supported in mvc..